# Rules for PerformSelectorInBackground

Tags: objective-c, performselector

I heard that the views can have their attributes changed only in the main thread, and never in a secondary thread, which makes certain background processing, unfortunately I did not found any practical example of it.

Could someone give me an example of a command that does not work inside a method that is being executed in background?

Comment: Everything that is directly related to GUI needs to be called from the main thread. Examples: addSubview, removeSubview, setFrame, setBackgroundColor etc...

Comment: I just want to say thank you :)

Comment: Glad to be of help ;)

Comment: Since it seems to answer Your question, I posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is directly related to GUI needs to be called from the main thread.
Examples:

```
- addSubview
- removeSubview
- setFrame
- setBackgroundColor
- etc...
```